# Playing a sound in a Class while loading a Data Classifier

Tags: java, android

I'm making an app that classifies images using 'tensorflow' in Android Studio, and I want to play a sound in the 'ImageClassifier' Java Class while the data indicates something.

**I get the following error: error (can't resolve method "create(class name ,int)"**
So the program will not run. Is there any way to play a sound in this class  while handling something else simultaneously?

```
 public class ImageClassifier {


 private void some_method{
     setupMediaPlayer();
  }

 public void setupMediaPlayer(){
  MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = 
  MediaPlayer.create(ImageClassifier.this,R.raw.sound);
  mediaPlayer.start();
 }

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The static method `create` you are trying to use of `MediaPlayer` expects a context as first parameter but you are providing a class name.

You can proceed this way:

- change the method `setupMediaPlayer` by adding a parameter of type Context that you will use to create your MediaPlayer.

```java
public void setupMediaPlayer(Context context){
  MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = 
  MediaPlayer.create(context,R.raw.sound);
  mediaPlayer.start();
 }
```

Comment: thanks alot it helped me with some modification in other fragment to pass context there too and the app runs as i want thanks